# Play framework: passing multiple implicit parameters through templates

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I'm using Play 2.0.2 and I'm having a problem with implicit parameters in one particular view template setup.  I'll describe it the best I can but it's not exactly trivial so I apologize in advance for any confusion.

Central to the issue is a template I have called "piece".  piece takes these parameters:

```
@(piecesData: objects.PiecesDataRequest)(implicit content: Html)
```

The content parameter is implicit because I am calling this template from another template as well as from a controller.  I could not find a way to explicitly pass "empty" Html to the piece template from the controller, however it works if I implicitly pass the content param.  The template using piece is "pieceUploadModal" which takes these parameters:

```
@(piecesData: objects.PiecesDataRequest, 
  pieceData: objects.PieceDataRequest, dialogTitle: String)
```

and calls piece like this:

```
@pieces(piecesData){ [Html] }
```

Now I want to add a second implicit param to piece which changes its param list too:

```
@(piecesData: objects.PiecesDataRequest)(implicit content: Html, user: User)
```

and I assumed then that I would need to change the pieceUploadModal template params too:

```
@(piecesData: objects.PiecesDataRequest, 
  pieceData: objects.PieceDataRequest, dialogTitle: String)(implicit user: User)
```

And be good to go... however, I get an error that isn't very helpeful:

```
pieceUploadModal.template.scala:24: not enough arguments for method apply: 
(implicit      content: play.api.templates.Html, 
implicit user: models.User)play.api.templates.Html in object pieces.
[error] Unspecified value parameter user.
[error] """),_display_(Seq[Any]
(/*3.2*/views/*3.7*/.html.content.pieces(piecesData)/*3.39*/
{_display_(Seq[Any] (format.raw/*3.40*/("""
```

I have been trying to get this to work in many different ways for a couple of hours and done numerous internet searches to no avail.  Any help would be appreciated.

As a last piece of information, I will add that the paradigm I'm using here of passing the user implicitly works with all of my other templates that are *not* using the implicit Html parameter, i.e. I believe that is the crux of the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

> I could not find a way to explicitly pass "empty" Html to the piece template from the controller

Empty Html can be passed with `Html("")`, you can even define it as a default value.

But in the end you just have to listen to compiler - it never lies. From your comments I understand this is how you defined your template:

`(piecesData: controllers.objects.PiecesDataRequest)(content: play.api.templates.Html)(implicit user: models.User)`

and this is how you call it:

`views.html.content.pieces(PiecesDataRequest( Piece.getPiecesForContentFeed(contentFeedID), contentFeedID), Html(""))`

You define three parens, but you are calling only two. Do it like this:

```
Ok(
   views.html.content.pieces(
       PiecesDataRequest(Piece.getPiecesForContentFeed(contentFeedID), contentFeedID))(Html(""))
   )
)
```

Comment: Actually, I tried both of those methods for passing empty Html - try it, it didn't work for me.  Secondly, your explanation about mixing explicit and implicit makes sense... I did try swapping the html and user params - didn't work.  Making it explicit kinda defeats the purpose - avoiding passing the user through every single controller call to a view using pieces.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work, what's the error? I'm using empty Html in my templates all the time.

Comment: If I set the content param like this @(...)(content: Html = Html("")) and call from my controller, I get this error:  Pieces.scala:48: missing arguments for method apply in object pieces;
[error] follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
[error]       Ok(views.html.content.pieces( PiecesDataRequest( Piece.getPiecesForContentFeed(contentFeedID), contentFeedID)))               I have tried the suggestion to partially apply the function but I just get different errors not matter what.

Comment: If I try to pass the Html param from my controller, like this:  Ok(views.html.content.pieces( PiecesDataRequest( Piece.getPiecesForContentFeed(contentFeedID), contentFeedID), Html("")))          then I get this error:   Pieces.scala:48: too many arguments for method apply: (piecesData: controllers.objects.PiecesDataRequest)(content: play.api.templates.Html)(implicit user: models.User)play.api.templates.Html in object pieces
[error]       Ok(views.html.content.pieces( PiecesDataRequest( Piece.getPiecesForContentFeed(contentFeedID), contentFeedID), Html("")))

Comment: And many permutations of both solutions... I just end up with the same or different compile errors

Comment: I would add that I have found a work-around where I create a "passthrough" template to call from the controller such that the passthrough simply calls pieces like @pieces([pieces explicit params]){}       this works.  So it seems logical that there is a way to do what you're suggesting w/o the passthrough, I just haven't found it.  I was waiting to suggest my workaround as the "answer" until others had a chance to respond and/or you and I found a better answer :)

Comment: Sometimes you just have to read what the compiler tells you. You're calling the template with the wrong number of arguments, I'll edit my answer.